# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run driver.js which is currently under /var/www/html/bot/ with the command "nodejs driver". But whenever I type this command I get the following error.

```
/var/www/html/bot/driver.js:296
  });
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1149:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I was not able to find any kind of syntax error in driver.js. Nevertheless, I am uploading the driver.js to hopefully find some help.

https://gist.github.com/dorukalpulgen/dfec87cfa0b0fa4c682eb91501c66b4a

Please help me with this one. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you using? If you can't find syntax errors otherwise, the program may be using syntax that's too modern for your Node.

Comment: That said, that particular line in your driver.js seems to be a bona fide syntax error; even my editor complains about it.

Comment: It's v14.0.0 I wasn't able to see anything although it directly refers to line 296. Did you find anything?

Comment: I'm not inclined at all to read through the 296 first lines to find where that brace might really belong to.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you remove `});` from lines 296 and 1635 and test it again??

Comment: Can you post the code itself?

Comment: I tried it as well, going to share the error code in a few minutes. I also published the whole driver.js under GitHub and put a link there. You can access the code on the link above.

Comment: When I delete line 296 and 1635 it gives me the error https://gist.github.com/dorukalpulgen/0470ab20fb50e6e801a462d0e19a5b35

Comment: Well, the first thing to do is to break this gargantuan block of code into more discrete functions across several modules.  That will make the problem smaller and more manageable and much easier to solve.

Comment: This is a long-axx file man.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my code editor. This should work.

Delete the `});` above `socket.on('disconnect', function () {` around line 296
and another `});` above

```
setInterval(function () {

    var online = Object.keys(users).length;
    io.sockets.emit('users online', online);
}, 5000);
```

around line 1634

Comment: I tried, things changed a bit Error: https://gist.github.com/dorukalpulgen/f77d34d6bffe2e0632613082b8b5e8f9 New File: https://gist.github.com/dorukalpulgen/eb8f342c5906d19d9a50eafe3873c52f

Comment: You gotta run `npm i` man. Should be good that way. I even get your code to run on my rig.

Comment: I am terribly sorry but I am not really familiar with the commands. Normally, I just use "nodejs driver". What should I use now?

Comment: Run `npm i` in the root directory. After it has finished, run `node driver`

Comment: I did what you told but now I get this: https://gist.github.com/dorukalpulgen/c42089326127117a5b02649ec9f0e845 do you have discord or something else to communicate easier?

Comment: I can't help you edit the whole js file man. Close this question and open a new one.